# How to count overall size of files in directory

Tags: bash

I would like to count overall size of files in some given directory via bash. What's the best approach to do that giben thaht i would be grateful if there was an option to optionaly show result in different units: MBs, GBs.

Comment: Just the files in directory itself or do you need to count all files in all subdirectories of that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` command is what you are looking for.

Type : `du -hs folder/*`

`-s` calculate total size in folder
`-h` makes it human readable

Answer (score 0):

For grins and giggles, you can also use `ls` and `awk`.  With this method, you can choose the units by using multiple divisions of 1024.

```
# Sum in bytes
ls -1l | grep -v ^total | awk '{sum += $5 } END { print sum "b"}'

# Sum in Kilobytes
ls -1l | grep -v ^total | awk '{sum += $5 } END { print sum/1024 "KB"}'

# Sum in Megabytes
ls -1l | grep -v ^total | awk '{sum += $5 } END { print sum/1024/1024 "MB"}'

# Sum in Gigabytes
ls -1l | grep -v ^total | awk '{sum += $5 } END { print sum/1024/1024/1024 "GB"}'
```